# what is the best way to show settingoptions in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, uiswitch

I have a fragment where the user need to add data that wil be saved.
But there is a switch where the user can choise if he want to add info.
If he wants to, it need to add some Edittext fields in de fragment.
Otherwhise it doesn't need to show those fields.

[image: Fragment]

What is the best way to do this properly?

Comment: If you are using a [`PreferenceFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html), you are looking for [android:dependency](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:dependency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the add "info button" is toggled to show the info buttons, set the visibility property on the "Add info A/B here" TextViews to Visible.  When the "info button" is toggled to not show the info buttons, set the visibility to Gone.

```
myTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
myTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this EditText in your XML but set their visibility to gone and then when the user clicked on switch just visible the items